# How can I detect when my android takes a new picture(create a new file from the camera) using a service component?

Tags: android, image, service

I need to detect, by a android service component, that monitors when the user takes a new picture.

I think to use FileObserver to check new files into DCIM directory but this approach will consume much battery, is there an other way to do this?

Comment: There is no requirement that when "the user take a new picture", that the result is a file that you can access.

Comment: no, any picture: is there any event associated with creating a new picture from the camera?

Comment: No. Again, there is no requirement that apps that use the camera hardware let third parties know that pictures were taken, let alone allow those pictures to be accessed by third parties

Comment: Mark Murphy, pardon me if I did can not make me understood but I found this link [http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-does-google-plus-instant-upload-work/] to do what I need.